# Unable to set href in angular 4 on nginx server

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-routing, angular-resource, nginx-reverse-proxy

Please bear with me as it's a long question but I am stuck badly.

**Objective**

I want to ran my ssl configured build on my linux based server on Nginx and I want to access it on my domain **https://dev.server.nl** with resources **/ggmd/webconsole** i.e **https://dev.server.nl/ggmd/webconsole**

**Steps I followed**

I have deployed my angular 4 build on my linux server machine in **webconsole** folder. Path is something like  /opt/web/dev/ggmd/webconsole and all my build files are inside it.

[image: webconsole]

I have ran build on nginx server by doing configuration in **default** file.

```
server {
    listen 4200 default_server;
    root /opt/web/dev/ggmd/webconsole;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

And my base href is set to `<base href="/ggmd/webconsole/">`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>GGMD Console</title>
    <base href="/ggmd/webconsole/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

My mapping configurations to access URl on domain is following:

```
location /ggmd/webconsole {
        proxy_pass http://13.26.100.155:4200;
        proxy_redirect http://13.26.100.155:4200 https://dev.w-integrate.nl/ggmd/webconsole;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

**Problem Statement**

1. I am unable to access it via IP on https but when I try to access via **HTTP** http://13.26.100.155:4200/ggmd/webconsole/

I redirected to 404 page of my angular application that I defined and made in my angular router code.

2. When I tried to access with redirect proxy then I am unable to access it on http but When I try https on **https://dev.w-integrate.nl/ggmd/web/console**

I get following error in browser console.

**Refused to execute script from inline.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.**

[image]

When I remove "**/ggmd/webconsole/**" from my base href and redirect configuration like following

`<base href="/">` and my redirect configurations to following

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://13.26.100.155:4200;
            proxy_redirect http://13.26.100.155:4200 https://dev.w-integrate.nl/;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
```

Then I am able to access my project on following

https://dev.server.nl/

http://13.26.100.155:4200 (NOT on HTTPS)

But I want to ran it on https and with /ggmd/webconsole resource https://dev.server.nl/ggmd/webconsole

How can I do this? Please forgive in case of any typing mistake.

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

port 443 was already in use with some other certificates under **server tag server { //configurations }**

I added my configurations in server tag below the **server tag where port is 443** and Base href is "/"

My configurations are below:

```
server {
    listen 4200 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /opt/web/dev/ggmd/webconsole/devcom.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /opt/web/dev/ggmd/webconsole/devcom.key;

    root /opt/web/dev/ggmd/webconsole;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name dev.w-integrate.nl;

        location /ggmd/webconsole(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass https://83.96.205.55:4200;
        proxy_redirect https://83.96.205.55:4200 https://dev.w-integrate.nl/ggmd/webconsole;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Now I am able to access https but following is happening:

**Via IP https://13.26.100.155:4200/ggmd/webconsole**

I am routed to 404 page of my angular application via angular route and

**Via reverse proxy https://dev.server.nl/ggmd/webconsole/**

I am routed to 404 page of nginx

What is wrong now?

Comment: firstly what's the purpose of adding a base href

Comment: The reason you are getting the above error is because you have specified an exact match of the nginx url. When you say ```location /ggmd/webconsole``` Only a request which hits the above url will go into the location block. If you have a request like ```/ggmd/webconsole/inline.js``` this will go into the default ```/``` block and for a javascript file will load an html file as per your config. This explains the mime type error. What you need it to put a regex. Something like ```location /ggmd/webconsole(.*)$ { ...```

Comment: Also For https you need to listen to a default port of 443.

Comment: @ Nitish Phanse so we can access resources in that way. /ggmd/webconsole

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if this file works

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name <YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME eg www.example.com>;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/rapid_ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/tp/cert/rapid_ssl.key;

        location /ggmd/webconsole(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://13.26.100.155:4200;
        proxy_redirect http://13.26.100.155:4200 https://dev.w-integrate.nl/ggmd/webconsole;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have two two files inside nginx folder one is where i have configured all locations of my server and second is default one. I have ran my project in default file which file should i do change in?

Comment: Where ever you have configured the above server block.. that is where you make the change..```location /ggmd/webconsole(.*)$``` is the imp bit and the port no for https is 443

Comment: I have updated my question can u please look into it  @Nitish Phanse